# docker aufs to devicemapper docker container and images migration

Tags: docker, storage, device-mapper

I'm on Ubuntu, changing default docker storage driver from aufs to devicemapper. I've some docker images and containers on aufs. i took backup of aufs storage files from /var/lib/docker .

how can i import aufs images and containers to devicemapper storage image and containers without loosing data respectively?

Answer (score 2):

You can [save images](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/) and [export containers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/export/) before changing the storage driver

```
docker save myImage1 > myImage1.tar
docker export myContainer1 > myContainer1.tar
```

Then you have to [load images](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/) and [import containers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/import/) after having changed the storage driver

```
docker load -i myImage1.tar
docker import /path/to/myContainer1.tar
```

Be careful that, as for official documentation:

> the docker export command does not export the contents of volumes
>   associated with the container. If a volume is mounted on top of an
>   existing directory in the container, docker export will export the
>   contents of the underlying directory, not the contents of the volume.
>
> Refer to [Backup, restore, or migrate data volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes) in the user guide
>   for examples on exporting data in a volume.